# Calculate the Moving Average Price (MAP)2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose we have an order table with three columns: an ID (ascending), the quantity and the total price. I want to calculate the moving average price (MAP)..

Looking at the first line where we purchased 10 pieces at a total price of 100$.

| ID | QUANTITY | TOTAL_PRICE | UNIT_COST (calculated) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 10.0 |

Then we add a purchase of 10 pieces at a higher total price of 200$.

| ID | QUANTITY | TOTAL_PRICE | UNIT_COST (calculated) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 10.0 |
| 2 | 10 | 200 | 15.0 |

```
select SUM(total_price) / SUM(quantity) AS unit_cost from tblItems;
```

The expected output is 15 (10 pieces at 10$ plus 10 pieces at 20$ makes a total of 20 pieces at an average price of 15$). If we sell 10 pieces, we'll get

| ID | QUANTITY | TOTAL_PRICE | UNIT_COST (calculated) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 10.0 |
| 2 | 10 | 200 | 15.0 |
| 3 | -10 | -300 | 15.0 |

The UNIT_COST cost at the time of sale was 15$. The stock is now down to 10 pieces again.

When buying the item again, 10 pieces at a total price of 100$, we'll get a stock of 10 pieces at 15$ and 10 pieces at 10$, in total 20 pieces at 12.5$.

| ID | QUANTITY | TOTAL_PRICE | UNIT_COST (calculated) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 10.0 |
| 2 | 10 | 200 | 15.0 |
| 3 | -10 | -300 | 15.0 |
| 4 | 10 | 100 | 12.5 |

After the new purchase the expected cost will be 12.5.

To do this in code c#

```
public class Model
{
  public decimal QUANTITY { get; set; }
  public decimal TOTAL_PRICE { get; set; }
  public decimal UNIT_COST { get; set; }
}
List<Model> _List = new List<Model>();
Model model = new Model();
model.QUANTITY = 10;
model.TOTAL_PRICE = 100;
_List.Add(model);
model = new Model();
model.QUANTITY = 10;
model.TOTAL_PRICE = 200;
_List.Add(model);
model = new Model();
model.QUANTITY = -10;
model.TOTAL_PRICE = -300;
_List.Add(model);
model = new Model();
model.QUANTITY = 10;
model.TOTAL_PRICE = 100;
_List.Add(model);

Model _model = new Model();
foreach (var item in _List)
{
    if (item != null)
    {
        if (item.QUANTITY < 0)
        {
            _model.QUANTITY = _model.QUANTITY + item.QUANTITY;
            _model.TOTAL_PRICE = (item.QUANTITY * _model.UNIT_COST) + _model.TOTAL_PRICE;
            _model.UNIT_COST = _model.TOTAL_PRICE / _model.QUANTITY;
        }
        else
        {
            _model.QUANTITY = _model.QUANTITY + item.QUANTITY;
            _model.TOTAL_PRICE = _model.TOTAL_PRICE + item.TOTAL_PRICE;
            _model.UNIT_COST = _model.TOTAL_PRICE / _model.QUANTITY;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(_model.UNIT_COST);
Console.ReadLine();
```

The question is, how can I inquire about the last cost of this item? .by query Sql

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73760791/calculate-the-moving-average-price-map)?

Comment: thank you sir . I deleted the previous question

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know I shouldn't delete the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is a recursive query. It calculates the `UNIT_COST` line by line and use the result for subsequent rows.

```
with StockCost as
(
      -- anchor member
      select ID, QUANTITY, TOTAL_PRICE, 
             BAL_QTY = QUANTITY,
             UNIT_COST = convert(decimal(10,2), TOTAL_PRICE / QUANTITY)
      from   Stock
      where  ID = 1

      union all

      -- recursive member
      select s.ID, s.QUANTITY, s.TOTAL_PRICE,
             BAL_QTY = c.BAL_QTY + s.QUANTITY,
             UNIT_COST = convert(decimal(10,2), 
                                 case when u.UNIT_COST IS NULL
                                      or   u.UNIT_COST = 0 
                                      then c.UNIT_COST 
                                      else u.UNIT_COST 
                                      end)
      from   Stock s
             inner join StockCost c on S.ID = c.ID + 1
             cross apply
             (
                 select UNIT_COST = ((c.UNIT_COST * BAL_QTY) + s.TOTAL_PRICE) 
                                  / NULLIF((c.BAL_QTY + S.QUANTITY), 0)
             ) u
)
select *
from   StockCost
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZHyeoAaz)